# script to recursively check for and select dependencies

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dependencies

I have written a script that does this but it is one of my first scripts ever so i am sure there is a better way:)

Let me know how you would go about doing this.
I'm looking for a simple yet efficient way to do this.

Here is some important background info:
( It might be a little confusing but hopefully by the end it will make sense. )

1) This shows the structure/location of the relevant dirs and files.

```
 main dir
 +-- config
   +-- default
     +-- config
       +-- config.file
       +-- package.file
 +-- package
   +-- $b
     +-- $a
       +-- $a.cache file
 +-- scripts
   +-- 40+ scripts
```

2) The packages.file located at `./config/default/config/packages` is a space delimited file.
field5 is the "package name" which i will call `$a` for explanations sake.
field4 is the name of the dir containing the `$a`.dir i will call `$b`
field1 shows if the package is selected or not,
"X"(capital x) for selected and "O"(capital o as in orange) for not selected.

Here is an example of what the packages.file might contain:

```
...  
X ---3------ 104.800 database gdbm 1.8.3 / base/library CROSS 0  
O -1---5---- 105.000 base libiconv 1.13.1 / base/tool CROSS 0  
X 01---5---- 105.000 base pkgconfig 0.25 / base/tool CROSS 0  
X -1-3------ 105.000 base texinfo 4.13a / base/tool CROSS DIETLIBC 0  
O -----5---- 105.000 develop duma 2_5_15 / base/development CROSS NOPARALLEL 0  
O -----5---- 105.000 develop electricfence 2_4_13 / base/development CROSS 0  
O -----5---- 105.000 develop gnupth 2.0.7 / extra/development CROSS NOPARALLEL FPIC-QUIRK 0   
...
```

3) For almost every package listed in the "packages.file" there is a corresponding ".cache file"
The .cache file for package $a would be located at `./package/$b/$a/$a.cache`
The .cache files contain a list of dependencies for that particular package.

Here is an example of one of the .cache files might look like.
Note that the dependencies are field2 of lines containing "[DEP]"
These dependencies are all names of packages in the "package.file"

```
[TIMESTAMP] 1134178701 Sat Dec 10 02:38:21 2005
[BUILDTIME] 295 (9)
[SIZE] 11.64 MB, 191 files

[DEP] 00-dirtree
[DEP] bash
[DEP] binutils
[DEP] bzip2
[DEP] cf
[DEP] coreutils
...
```

So with all that in mind...
I'm looking for a shell script that:

From within the "main dir"
Looks at the `./config/default/config/packages` file
and finds the "selected" packages
and reads the corresponding .cache
Then compiles a list of dependencies that excludes the already selected packages
Then selects the dependencies (by changing field1 to X) in the `./config/default/config/packages` file
and repeats until all the dependencies are met

Note: The script will ultimately end up in the "scripts dir" and be called from the "main dir".

If this is not clear let me know what need clarification.

For those interested I'm playing around with [T2 SDE](http://www.t2-project.org/).
If you are into playing around with linux it might be worth taking a look.
If you are going to post a script for me please make sure it is well commented to help me learn.

Answer (score 1):

tl'dr:) But about one week ago i needed a lightweight portable dependency solver. I've looked into `portage` - which is too ophidian, so to say. Then i had a look at `opkg`. `Opkg` almost worked, but then i read about some unusual ways to use `make`, and finally i felt happy with `make`. It's portable, does anything i need (with proper Makefile), and it has innate ability to grok the dependencies.

Frankly speaking, the idea of writing dependency solver in shell frightens me somehow, and being lazy i would rather use something that already exists.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how make (with proper Makefile) would resolve your dependencies?